# Getting SMTP server connection error while sending mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am getting a server error while sending email.

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at...

```
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                message.From = new MailAddress("email");
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress(toEmailAddress));

                message.Subject = "Order Confirmation - Bahwan Electronics";
                message.IsBodyHtml = true; //to make message body as html  
                message.Body = htmlString;
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //for gmail host  
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email", "password");
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

                smtp.Send(message);
                return true;
            }
```

I tried above code it is working fine in Local but when I hosted it in server I am getting above error.
No two factor auth is enabled in email and also enabled less secure apps.

I am not able to find any solution from the previous questions asked for the same issue.
And tried all the solutions. It is working on local but after hosting it *smtp.Send* method throws error.

Comment: Note I removed [core] tag, if you meant .net core check the appropriate tag.

Comment: I think the problem is that some authentification token is missing. The host you're trying to send from needs to be trusted, so go and configure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution for the above issue.

Taken a remote of the hosting server and logged in to gmail with the emailId which I am using to send mail, and then on the review user activity on gmail I just added that device as "Yes its me".

After that mail started working..